# Creating a map with pathfinding in android

Tags: java, android

I am currently on a project on android development. I want to create a map with pathfinding(where it highlights the shortest path between two points that you have selected on a map) in android.

I have android studio and I have also created a map in .png file. I would be using A-star search as my pathfinding algorithm. The current location is manually set by the user so it does not need to enable gps.

So what are the things that I need to do?

I'm new to android but I'm really good at java so any answer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Drawing Map you can use this code:

Call for printing location route:

```
   GmapV2Direction route;
   Document document;

 LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(routeData.get(i).latitude, routeData.get(i).longitude);
                        new GetRouteTask() {
                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                                super.onPostExecute(s);
                            }
                        }.execute((LatLng) toPosition);



private class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String> {

        String response = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            document = route.getDocument(fromPosition, params[0], GmapV2Direction.MODE_WALKING);//fromPosition is another LatLng object.can be your current location.
            response = "Success";
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            // directionMap.clear();

            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                Log.v("Map", "got here");
                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = route.getDirection(document);
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                        Color.RED);

                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                }
                // Adding route on the map

                map.addPolyline(rectLine);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: for more info u can knock me.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've updated my post. Kindly read my post. Sorry I havent put a more specific post.